# import users custom roles/attributes from custom web application (CMS) (already integrated with MS Azure AD) into MS Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, content-management-system

I have a custom CMS, that i already integrated with the Azure AD. (for now it's only authentication process for the AD users in the CMS via the oAuth/MS Graph by registering an Azure app so on... this way i'll have to manage the CMS users in only one place in Azure AD instead of the CMS too)
But the CMS users have custom roles (in the CMS, i'm not talking about the AD roles, ex: campaign management access, or Blog editor) and i don't know and i couldn't find yet anything regarding creating some attributes/custom roles in AD to be used in the CMS that is not related to Azure Services/SaaS.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Hi, do you have a chance to look into my answer? If there is anything unclear, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: @AllenWu thanks a lot, this was very helpful. i would vote your answer but i don't have the reputation yet

Comment: Hi, if my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). It's not voting the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add users in different roles into different Azure AD groups.

Then you can include Groups claim in your token as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes). Just need to modify the "groupMembershipClaims" field in application manifest:

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"
```

Then the token will contain the Ids of the groups that the use belongs to like below :

```
{
  "groups": ["group id"]
}
```

You can [define some application roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#examples) and [assign the roles to the groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-users-and-groups-to-roles). Then the users in the group will have the claim like below:

```
{
  "roles": ["{your custom role}"]
}
```

Then you can implement your authorization logic based on the roles of the user.